# I want to find greater common divisor by using iterator in python

Tags: python-3.x, iteration

I create program for finding grater common divisor in python.I don`t get answer when i use iterator in program.

```
class gcd:
    def __iter_(self):
        self.a = 4
        self.b = 6
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        a=self.a
        b=self.b
        if(self.a>self.b):
            min = self.b
        else:
            min = self.a
        for x in range(min,0,-1):
            if(self.a%x==0 and self.b%x==0):
                c=x
                break
        return c        
myclass = gcd()
myiter = iter(myclass)
var = next(myiter)
print(var)
#print(next(myiter))
```

I expect output of 4 & 6 is 2,but i get "gcd object is not iterable" as output.

Comment: There is an underscore missing at the end of `__iter_ `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an underscore here `def __iter_(self):`. Change this to `def __iter__(self):`.

Comment: thanks this take almost my one hour.